# Django tree models where two have manytomany relashionship

Tags: python, django

I have those models and i want to select specific data from all models

**Example:**

Consultatie.objects.filter(pacient=1)

get data from Diagnotic specific to that pacient

get data from Medicamentatie specific to that pacient

```
class Pacient(models.Model):
  name= models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Medicamentatie(models.Model):
  lista_medicament = models.ForeignKey(ListaMedicamente, on_delete=models.PROTECT, choices='')

class Diagnostic(models.Model):
    lista_boala = models.ForeignKey(ListaBoli, on_delete=models.PROTECT, choices='')
    medicamentatie_diagnostic = models.ManyToManyField(Medicamentatie)

class Consultatie(models.Model):
    pacient = models.ForeignKey(Pacient, on_delete=models.CASCADE, choices='')
    medic = models.ForeignKey(Medic, on_delete=models.PROTECT, choices='')
    diagnostic = models.ManyToManyField(Diagnostic)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try do something like this:

```
diagnostics_id_list = 
list(set(Consultatie.objects.filter(pacient=1).values_list('diagnostic', 
flat=True)))
diagnostics = Diagnostics.objects.filter(id__in=diagnostics_ids)
```

With this, you will get all the unique diagnostics for your patient.

Can't tell about Medicamentatie, because there is no ListaMedicamente model in your code.

Comment: Thanks! i will try. ListMedicamente is not so important... is only to select some data already inserted